# Is modifying data passed by const shared_ptr& Ok?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I've come across a situation where I needed to set a property to a library object by means of a setter accepting const shared_ptr reference. Here is a simple example:

```
// library class
class WidgetProxy {
public:
    void setName(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& name);
    // more methods
};
```

Suspecting nothing, I used it like this:

```
WidgetProxy widgetProxy(...);

auto name = std::make_shared<std::string>("Turing");
widgetProxy.setName(name);

// continue using `name`
```

Then I've found out that `name` had become empty after `setName()` call. Luckily, library source code was available and I was able to examine the implementation. It was roughly the following:

```
class WidgetImpl {
public:
    void setName(std::string name)
    {
        name_ = std::move(name);
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

void WidgetProxy::setName(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& name)
{
    widgetImpl_.setName(std::move(*name));
}
```

So `setName()` moves out the string wrapped by the `shared_ptr` which is formally not prohibited since `shared_ptr` template argument is `std::string` and not `const std::string`.

**My questions:**

1. Is it a normal design to implement `WidgetProxy::setName()` like this?
2. Should a library user normally expect such behavior when they see a `const shared_ptr<T>&` function parameter?

Upd: The posted code snippets are much simplified. In the library there is a different type in place of std::string. I have also omitted checks for pointer validity.

Comment: "Should a library user normally expect [this]" Yes. As paraphrased from Sean Parent, `shared_ptr`s are just fancy global variables. Unless the underlying object is `const` (not to be mistaken with a `shared_ptr<const T>`, which is a `const` view on an object which may or may not be `const`), mutation on the object should always be expected.
First question is pretty subjective.

Comment: RE #1: I can't say I'd have much confidence in a library that requires me to pass all my strings as shared_ptrs...

Comment: @djgandy, I've simplified the code a lot to make it suitable for an SO post. In reality there was a different type in place of std::string. Probably I should have mentioned it in the text.

Comment: My point still applies whatever the type tbh. Why pass by shared pointer if there are no shared semantics?

Comment: Would you think it sensible to pass a raw pointer by const reference? The answer for shared_ptr is the same.

Comment: Interesting reading: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a normal design to implement setName() like this?

This implementation style is OK:

```
void setName(std::string name)
{
    name_ = std::move(name);
}
```

The string is first copied by the function call, and the copied string is moved to the class member.  The resulting code is as efficient than passing a reference to a string, and then copying to the data member.

This one is not. And I do not not recommend it.

```
void WidgetProxy::setName(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& name)
{
    widgetImpl_.setName(std::move(*name));
}
```

For 2 reasons.  1: why require a std::shared_ptr if the pointer is not kept?  2: The net result of the operation deletes the string held by the pointee.  This affects all the other holders of the shared_ptr, some of which may need the value of the original string.

A more correct way to write this function, and the associated function call:

```
void WidgetProxy::setName(std::string name)
{
    widgetImpl_.setName(std::move(name));
}

// call as:
if (strPtr)
    proxy.setName(*strPtr);   // with strPtr being a std::shared_ptr<std::string>
```

> Should a library user normally expect such behavior when they see a const shared_ptr& function parameter?

No.  This is a terrible way of coding a library.  If the caller wishes to keep the string for any reason, he must create a shared_ptr with a copy of the original string.  Plus, the library code does not even check if the shared_ptr holds a valid pointer!  Very, very naughty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should mention that I've simplified the code a lot. The real code is more complex and it has a check for nullptr.

Comment: If would be nice of you to specify the library name in the original question, it is of public interest.

Comment: this is an internal library used in our company and not publically available, so the name will not tell you anything :)

Comment: Oh boy.  This will certainly lead to a tricky situation :).   Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what this means:

```
class WidgetProxy {
public:
  void setName(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& name);
};
```

`setName` takes a reference to a possibly mutable shared pointer that it does not have permission to modify.  This shared pointer refers to a mutable string.

This means within `setName`, whenever control flows out of what is visible to the compiler, the pointer and validity of `name` could change (and, you should check that it does not).

The value pointed to by this non-mutable view of a possibly mutable shared pointer is fully mutable.  You have full permission to modify it.

Some alternatives:

```
class WidgetProxy {
public:
  void setName(std::shared_ptr<std::string> name);
};
```

This is a local shared pointer to a mutable string.  It can only be modified locally, unless you leak references to it.  The data referred to be be manipulated by any other code, and must be assumed to be modified whenever local context is left.  It will, however, remain a valid pointer over the lifetime of the `setName` function unless you personally clear it.

```
class WidgetProxy {
public:
  void setName(std::shared_ptr<std::string const> name);
};
```

this is a local shared pointer to a string you do not have mutation rights to.  Someone else with a shared pointer to it could modify it if it is actually mutable at any point you leave local code, and should be presumed to be doing so.

```
class WidgetProxy {
public:
  void setName(std::string name);
};
```

this is a local copy of a buffer of characters that nobody else can modify within the function, and that you own.

```
class WidgetProxy {
public:
  void setName(std::string const& name);
};
```

this is a reference to a possibly mutable external `std::string` which must be presumed to be changed every time you leave local code in the function.

---

Personally, I see no reason why `WidgetProxy` is taking an arguments by `shared_ptr` or `const&`.  It doesn't use the shared-ness of the argument, nor does it want the value to be remotely changed on it.  It is a "sink" argument that it will consume, and the cost of moving the object is low.

`WidgetProxy::setName` should take a `std::string`.  Sink arguments of cheap-to-move data should take by-value.  And use of smart pointers here seems like a horrid idea; why complicate your life with `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Thanks, I totally understand that const shared_ptr<T> is a const pointer to mutable data. The issue is such interface being not intuitive (maybe only for me). Regarding your question why WidgetProxy takes an argument by shared_ptr, there is a reason for that in the library: without getting into much details, I can only say that WidgetProxy interface is determined by an abstract class it inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine for `WidgetImpl::setName()` to be implemented in this manner, as it is moving from local parameter.

It is simply a bug to implement `WidgetProxy::setName` this way, because you can't realistically expect the object managed by `shared_ptr` to be movable.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the first question to specify that it is about WidgetProxy::setName. (By the way, WidgetImpl class might be not visible to the library user at all).